# How can I prove these statements or provide a counterexample?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Let A, B, and C be sets. For each of the following, either prove the statement or give a counterexample.

(a) $n(A-B) ≤ nA$

(b) $nA ≤ nB ⟹ n(A×C) ≤ n(B×C)$

(c) $n(A-B) ≤ nB$

Notes:

$nA$ means the cardinal number of set $A$.
$n(A×C)$ means the cardinal number of set $A×C$.

$nA ≤ nB ⇐⇒$ There is an injection from A to B

$nA = nB ⇐⇒$ A ≈ B (A and B are equipotent)

$nA < nB ⇐⇒$ There is an injection but no bijection from A to B.

my work: (a) the mapping $x -> x$ is an injection from $A-B$ to $A$.

Comment: Hi, welcome to MSE.  A few pointers:  the title needs to be more specific, half the problems on this site could be called "hi please help".  Second, your notation is not defined.  I don't know what hashtag is supposed to mean, nor $ \leq $ in this context. Third, you need to learn the formatting, from a place like [this](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) Fourth and most importantly, we don't want to just do your homework for you. Show what you have tried, where you are stuck, list definitions if that's all you have. Show effort.

Comment: @RobertTheTutor thanks for the feedback. I have made the edits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$a)$: True, because $A \setminus B \subseteq A$.

$b)$: True. Since $|A| \le |B|$, there is an injective function $f: A \to B$. Define $g: A\times C \to B\times C$ by $g(a,c) = (f(a),c)$, then $g$ is also injective, proving the assertion.

$c)$: False. Take $A =\mathbb{R}, B = \mathbb{N}$, then $|A \setminus B | > |B|$.